# Survival Analysis: adjusting the Kaplan-Meier curve and optimal sample size?

Tags: survival, sample-size, cox-model, kaplan-meier

Following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujIMPpl2Tr0 from Stanford university, if the log-rank test (a popular test of Kaplan-Meier curves) does not contain report a statistically significant result but the Cox proportional hazards model test for the same variable *is* statistically significant, the curves should adjusted for possible confounding factors. C1, C2, C3 and C4 correspond to other classification of the disease by gene expression.

[image: unadjusted kaplan-meyer]
[image: cox regression in the look for confounding factors]
[image: adjusted kaplan-meyer to cox regression]

```
cox <- coxph(Surv(TIME_TO_DEATH_FROM_SURGERY, Morte.S.N) ~ Histologia +  Transcriptomic + 
Genomic + Sexo +Tratamento.adjuvante , data = clinical_data_clean)
ggadjustedcurves(cox, variable = 'Transcriptomic', data = clinical_data_clean)
```

Is it possible to add a p value for the second graph with the curves adjusted for confounding factors? And could you provide some feedback about the correctness of this analysis?

Thank you and best regards.